# Make UIAlertView have same title as the cell that was clicked to open it

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uialertview

I need the UIAlertView to have the same title as the cell that opened it. I already have an NSArray of names. So, for example, if I open a cell named White, the UIAlertView should have the title White. There has to be a specific AlertView title for every cell opened.

I already tried implementing the self.(name of array) method which doesn't seem to work when I do it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: @parisianastro97 If this answer has helped you, be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to the answer!